# Invalid Argument Supplied for foreach() in /.../Importblock.php on Line 67

Tags: magento2, php

I am using a theme and trying to **import blocks** has this **warning popup**:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/pluslivi/public_html/app/code/Rokanthemes/RokanBase/Controller/Adminhtml/Rokanbase/Importblock.php on line 67

When I go to the file to take a look at the error line -

```
foreach($data['root']['blocks']['item'] as $_item) {
            $exist = false;
            $collection = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Model\Block')->getCollection();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('identifier', $_item['identifier']);
            if($collection->getSize())
                $exist = true;
            $block = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Model\Block');
            if($overwrite) {
                if($exist) {
                    $conflictingOldItems[] = $_item['identifier'];
                    $block->load($_item['identifier']);
                }
            } else {
                if($exist) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            $conflictingOldItems[] = $_item['identifier'];
            $_item['store_id'] = array(0);
            $block->addData($_item)->save();
            $i++;
        }
```

Can someone help me out with this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: print_r($data); before your foreach loop. It will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **$data['root']['blocks']['item']** is array or not before looping. Try following way:

```
if (isset($data['root']['blocks']['item']) && is_array($data['root']['blocks']['item'])) {
    foreach($data['root']['blocks']['item'] as $_item) {
        $exist = false;
        $collection = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Model\Block')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('identifier', $_item['identifier']);
        if($collection->getSize())
            $exist = true;
        $block = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Model\Block');
        if($overwrite) {
            if($exist) {
                $conflictingOldItems[] = $_item['identifier'];
                $block->load($_item['identifier']);
            }
        } else {
            if($exist) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        $conflictingOldItems[] = $_item['identifier'];
        $_item['store_id'] = array(0);
        $block->addData($_item)->save();
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Tried it your way it and worked perfectly.